# Transitive dependencies getting excluded by gradle

Tags: gradle

Context: So I have a complex build where dependencies may be 4 or 5 projects deep. What I'm seeing is that the final war project doesn't appear to be bringing in any of the dependencies from other sub-projects. I have a few sub-projects that represent just dependencies. I have the Spring dependency management plug-in that supports maven BOM's. These are used by multiple subprojects such that several have the same dependency meaning that I have several paths to the same **project** dependency. I've noticed that if I comment some of them out, some of my dependencies show up. Now here is the frustrating part. There's not one single exclude in here anywhere. I removed them all to make sure it wasn't me and for the most part, they don't seem to be needed.

BTW, this is going to be tough because I'll either have not enough code to show you or WAY to much and, of course, all of it would have to be redacted for security.

`gradle dependencies --configuration compile` shows only the top level projects.

Clue?

Comment: If you can, creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help out both you and anyone trying to answer.

Comment: `gradle projects` will show all projects in a hierarchical build if this can help you figure out what is going on.